# Unable to pull from git in psexec mode

Tags: git, stack-overflow, psexec

Everything is working fine when I am pulling from local login but when I tried to login to Windows 7 git version 2.28.0.windows.1 through PSEXEC, and tried to pull the changes it is displaying

```
git.exe :
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:String) [], RemoteException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException.
bash: /dev/tty: No such device or address
error: failed to execute prompt script (exit code 1)
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such file or directory
```

this is only happening when I tried to pull from PSEXEC mode even though I am also logged in as an administrator and through the same local account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error could be linked to:

- a private repository (meaning you need authentication for each Git remote command like a pull)
- a credential helper (check what `git config credential.helper` return through psexec)

If there is an interactive process asking for the username, try as a workaround/test to include said username in the HTTPS URL:

```
git remote set-url origin https://<username>@github.com/<username>/<myrepo>
```

The [OP Siva Manasan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7339043/siva-manasan) reports in the comments it works when specifying both the username and password.

```
git remote set-url origin  https://<username>:<password>@github.com/<username>/<myrepo>.git
```

Ideally, if a recent enough version of [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) (and its associated  [microsoft / Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows)) is installed on the remote machine accessed by [psexec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec).

First check where Git is installed on the remote machine:

```
psexec <...parameters for remote machine> where git
```

Then use the remote credential helper to register the password:

```sh
psexec <params> [path\to\git]\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git-credential-manager.exe store < afile

# with afile:
protocol=https
host=github.com
username=some-account
password=personaltoken
```

Note: it is better to use a [PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token) than your actual password: safer, and you can revoke the PAT at any time without having to change the password.

Then a simple URL with only your username should be enough:

```
git remote set-url origin  https://<username>@github.com/<username>/<myrepo>.git
```

Comment: the thing is everything is working fine including `git pull` when I do it from local login, it is only giving this error when I do it through PSEXEC. I tried `git config credential.helper` through PSEXEC and it returned `manager` and the remote-url is already set

Comment: @SivaManasan Can you try and set the remote URL with the username, for testing?

Comment: I tried it and got the error 


git.exe : usage: git remote set-url [--push] <name> <newurl> [<oldurl>]
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (usage: git remo...url> [<oldurl>]:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

   or: git remote set-url --add <name> <newurl>
   or: git remote set-url --delete <name> <url>
    --push                manipulate push URLs
    --add                 add URL
    --delete              delete URLs

Comment: @SivaManasan Sorry, i missed the remote name. I have edited the answer.

Comment: I tried your new edit and it said the password was missing so I used `git remote set-url origin  https://<username>:<password>@github.com/<username>/<myrepo>.git` and everything is working now including git pull

Comment: @SivaManasan OK. Ideally, you would cache the password in the credential helper. I have edited the answer to propose that.